# I have "Run-time error 424" Object required in Outlook VBA code

Tags: vba, email, outlook, runtime-error, email-attachments

I started to create a code to download specific attachments to a disk folder, but i have a Run-time error 424 somewhere in the `Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Inbox").Items`   `Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Test").Items` part. I don't know for what reason and can't figure it out. I am still not declared which exactly attachments i need to be downloaded, but want  to see if it works at first place. Can you check it-out and tell me where i'm wrong/missing something, please?
Here's the code :

```
'ThisOutlookSession part

Private WithEvents rvItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim rvApp As Outlook.Application
Dim rvNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set rvApp = Outlook.Application
Set rvNS = rvApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set rvInbox = rvNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Inbox").Items
Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Test").Items

End Sub


'Modules part
Private Sub rvItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

Dim rvMail As Outlook.mailitem
Dim rvAtt As Outlook.Attachment

If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

Set rvMail = item
   
 For Each rvAtt In rvMail.Attachments
    rvAtt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\BG-TRADE-005\OneDrive - alpiq.com\Desktop\Schedule\Mail_Temp \Download" & rvAtt.FileName
  Next rvAtt

  Set rvMail = Nothing

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: You should find it easier to find errors such as the missing `rvFolder` if you use`OptionExplicit`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are trying to assign an Outlook type instead of using the `Application` property:

```
Set rvApp = Outlook.Application
```

So, the code should re-use the global `Application` property available in the Outlook VBA environment.

```
Private WithEvents rvItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim rvNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim rvInbox as Outlook.Folder

Set rvNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set rvInbox = Application.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Test").Items

End Sub


'Modules part
Private Sub rvItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

Dim rvMail As Outlook.mailitem
Dim rvAtt As Outlook.Attachment

If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

Set rvMail = item
   
 For Each rvAtt In rvMail.Attachments
    rvAtt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\BG-TRADE-005\OneDrive - alpiq.com\Desktop\Schedule\Mail_Temp \Download" & rvAtt.FileName
  Next rvAtt

  Set rvMail = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

If the problem still persists and the code can't locate the `Test` folder I'd suggest iterating over all subfolders and checking the `Name` property. Following that way you can find the required folder without errors.

Also you need to pay attention to the fact that in the code Items and Folder instances are mixed:

```
Set rvInbox = rvNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Inbox").Items
Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Test").Items
```

You are trying to get a subfolder on the `Items` instance where such property doesn't exists.

If you need to get a subfolder of the Inbox folder you need to use the following code instead:

```
Set rvInbox = rvNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Test").Items
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I just made the changes, but now the code tells me "Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method for the line `Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Inbox").Items`

Comment: You need to define objects in the code if you didn't so.

Comment: `Dim rvInbox as Outlook.Folder`

Comment: i added this line, deleted a space in  `rvAtt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\BG-TRADE-005\OneDrive - alpiq.com\Desktop\Schedule\Mail_Temp \Download" & rvAtt.FileName` line, but still have yellow line at `Set rvInbox = Application.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items`

Comment: You don't need to use the Items property on the Inbox folder.

Comment: I've updated the post, so you may see where the problem is.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question in a separate thread, so readers could recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: I still get this Runtime error in Set rvItems = rvFolder.Folders("Test").Items line....
Does it matters that i am using Outlook 365?

Comment: Are you sure that such folder exists in the folder tree in your Outlook 365?

Comment: Yes, of course : I don't know how can i upload a pic of my Inbox tree to see what i'm trying to achieve, but yes - i have it under Inbox.

Comment: Try to iterate over all subfolders and check their names. Following that way you can get the required instance.

Comment: It's done couple of times but still no effect. Did the name of the sub folder matters like this : now i have "Meteologica SA Power Forecast" as source folder, but if it's like this : "MeteologicaSAPowerForecast"? I mean without the spaces?